# Unity3d 5.6 VR Cardboard application incorrectly displays on device

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I've just installed `Unity3d 5.6` and build application for Android with native VR support for Cardboard SDK (checking box `Virtual Reality Supported` and selecting Cardboard as VR SDK). App responds to movements of device, however, picture is not correctly takes only part of screen, what can cause that issue?

Built for Android 5.0, run on Android 5.1 Sony Z2, device is configured for cardboard viewer with Google Cardboard application, other VR games take all screen at expected.

[image]

Added:

As per advice on Unity forum I enabled `Multithreded rendering`, however it resulted in almost good, still not properly centered image flicked momentarely, then blank (lenses viewes disappeared).

[image]

[image]

Comment: you know that 5.6 is a beta version, don't you? You should report issues with betas to Unity's bugtracker and stick with normal releases for production.

Answer (score 1):

If you are manually setting the screen resolution by script (Screen.SetResolution) try commenting that out.

Answer (score 0):

As written in Unity forum here:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/google-vr-sdk-1-10-unity-5-5-broken.445323/

for VR for cardboard development it' better for now to stick to using Unity 5.4.2 with Google VR SDK 10.3.

Comment: Hi there - is the same true for Unity 5.6.1p1? Is it broken for Cardboard VR? And is it also broken for GearVR? Any suggestions?